# Join multiple tables of Amazon Redshift in a single one obtains error: column X is of type boolean but expression is of type character varying Hint:

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to join multiple tables of Amazon Redshift in a single one.
One of the initial tables is this one:

```
create table order_customers(
  id int,
  email varchar(254),
  phone varchar(50),
  customer_id int,
  order_id int NOT NULL,
  ip text,
  geoip_location varchar(1024),
  logged_in boolean,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders (id)
);
```

I am using the command to insert the data into the large table:

```
INSERT INTO orders_large ( id, showid, created_at, status, status_enum, currency, tax_orders, shipping, discount_orders, 
  subtotal, total, store_id, payment_method_id, shipping_method_name, shipping_method_id, additional_information,
  payment_information, locale, shipping_required_orders, payment_method_type, coupons, payment_notification_id,     
  recover_token, updated_at, external, shipping_tax, shipping_discount, shipping_discount_decimal,  
  completed_at, payment_name, shipping_service_id, app_id, fulfillment_status, date_traffic_sources,
  landing_url,  referral_url, referral_code, utm_campaign, utm_source, utm_term, utm_medium, utm_content,       
  user_agent, subscription_id_traffic_sources, email, phone, customer_id_order_customers,    
  ip, geoip_location, logged_in, name, surname, company, address, street_number, city, postal, country, region,
  type, taxid, default_, region_format, municipality, latitude, longitude, subscription_id_addresses,
  customer_id_addresses, pickup_point_id, taxid_type, sku, qty, price, product_id, weight, 
  product_option_property_id, discount_order_products, shipping_required_orders_products, brand, 
  tax_order_products, width, height, length, volume, diameter, package_format)
SELECT o.id, o.showid, o.created_at, o.status, o.status_enum, o.currency, o.tax, o.shipping, o.discount, 
  o.subtotal, o.total, o.store_id, o.payment_method_id, o.shipping_method_name, o.shipping_method_id, o.additional_information,
  o.payment_information, o.locale, o.shipping_required, payment_method_type, coupons, payment_notification_id,     
  recover_token, o.updated_at, o.external, shipping_tax, o.shipping_discount, shipping_discount_decimal,  
  completed_at, payment_name, shipping_service_id, o.app_id, o.fulfillment_status, t.date,
  t.landing_url, t.referral_url, t.referral_code, t.utm_campaign, t.utm_source, t.utm_term, t.utm_medium, t.utm_content,       
  t.user_agent, t.subscription_id, oc.email, oc.phone, oc.customer_id, oc.order_id, oc.ip,
  oc.geoip_location, oc.logged_in, a.name, a.surname, a.company, a.address, a.street_number, a.city, a.postal,
  a.country, a.region, a.type, a.taxid, a.default_, a.region_format, a.municipality, a.latitude, a.longitude, a.order_id,
  a.subscription_id, a.customer_id, a.pickup_point_id, a.taxid_type, op.sku, op.qty, op.price, op.product_id,
  op.order_id, op.weight, op.product_option_property_id, op.discount, op.shipping_required, op.brand, 
  op.tax, op.width, op.height, op.length, op.volume, op.diameter, op.package_format
FROM  orders o
INNER JOIN traffic_sources t ON o.id = t.order_id
INNER JOIN order_customers oc ON  o.id = oc.order_id
INNER JOIN addresses a ON  o.id = a.order_id
INNER JOIN order_products op ON  o.id = op.order_id;
```

An I obtain this error mensage:

```
ERROR: column "logged_in" is of type boolean but expression is of type character varying Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I try using DECODE(oc.logged_in, 'false', '0', 'true', '1')::varchar::bool in the oc.logged_in field, but another error message appears:

```
ERROR: cannot cast type character varying to boolean
```

Comment: Why are you decoding into a string value and then trying to coerce it into a boolean? I'd expect `DECODE(oc.logged_in, 'false', false, 'true', true, NULL)` or `DECODE(oc.logged_in, 'false', false, true)` would be what you'd want.

Comment: Both options return "ERROR: column "logged_in" is of type boolean but expression is of type character varying Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression."

Comment: I also tryied DECODE(oc.logged_in, 'false', false, true)::Boolean, DECODE(oc.logged_in, 'false', false, 'true', true, NULL)::Boolean, DECODE(oc.logged_in, 'true', true, false)::Bool and the error is always the same "ERROR: column "logged_in" is of type boolean but expression is of type character varying Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression."

Answer (score 0):

As the message says - column "logged_in" is of type boolean

So in your DECODE you need to compare it to boolean values, not strings.  Try:

```
DECODE(oc.logged_in, true, 'true', 'false')
```

```
The code above works for my understanding of you issue.  Below is test SQL which runs fine on Redshift.  

    create table oc as (select 1=1 as logged_in union all select 1=0);
    select * from oc;
    select DECODE(oc.logged_in, true, 'true string', 'false string') as test from oc;

I now expect that the issue is not in using oc.logged_in but rather with orders_large.logged_in and what you are putting in it.  What data type is logged_in defined as in orders_large?  Boolean, I assume.  Which should take a boolean value just fine w/o casting.  

Looking at your SQL I see that the number of elements in INSERT clause doesn't match the number of elements in the SELECT clause.  This mismatch is causing your SQL to try and put a different (text) value into orders_large.logged_in.  Here's a "diff" between the 2 lists (SELECT on the left / INSERT on the right):

    id                              id
    showid                              showid
    created_at                          created_at
    status                              status
    status_enum                         status_enum
    currency                            currency
    tax_orders                            | tax
    shipping                            shipping
    discount_orders                           | discount
    subtotal                            subtotal
    total                               total
    store_id                            store_id
    payment_method_id                       payment_method_id
    shipping_method_name                        shipping_method_name
    shipping_method_id                      shipping_method_id
    additional_information                      additional_information
    payment_information                     payment_information
    locale                              locale
    shipping_required_orders                      | shipping_required
    payment_method_type                     payment_method_type
    coupons                             coupons
    payment_notification_id                     payment_notification_id
    recover_token                           recover_token
    updated_at                          updated_at
    external                            external
    shipping_tax                            shipping_tax
    shipping_discount                       shipping_discount
    shipping_discount_decimal                   shipping_discount_decimal
    completed_at                            completed_at
    payment_name                            payment_name
    shipping_service_id                     shipping_service_id
    app_id                              app_id
    fulfillment_status                      fulfillment_status
    date_traffic_sources                          | date
    landing_url                         landing_url
    referral_url                            referral_url
    referral_code                           referral_code
    utm_campaign                            utm_campaign
    utm_source                          utm_source
    utm_term                            utm_term
    utm_medium                          utm_medium
    utm_content                         utm_content
    user_agent                          user_agent
    subscription_id_traffic_sources                   | subscription_id
    email                               email
    phone                               phone
    customer_id_order_customers                   | customer_id
                                      > order_id
    ip                              ip
    geoip_location                          geoip_location
    logged_in                           logged_in
    name                                name
    surname                             surname
    company                             company
    address                             address
    street_number                           street_number
    city                                city
    postal                              postal
    country                             country
    region                              region
    type                                type
    taxid                               taxid
    default_                            default_
    region_format                           region_format
    municipality                            municipality
    latitude                            latitude
    longitude                           longitude
    subscription_id_addresses                     | order_id
    customer_id_addresses                         | subscription_id
                                      > customer_id
    pickup_point_id                         pickup_point_id
    taxid_type                          taxid_type
    sku                             sku
    qty                             qty
    price                               price
    product_id                          product_id
                                      > order_id
    weight                              weight
    product_option_property_id                  product_option_property_id
    discount_order_products                       | discount
    shipping_required_orders_products                 | shipping_required
    brand                               brand
    tax_order_products                        | tax
    width                               width
    height                              height
    length                              length
    volume                              volume
    diameter                            diameter
    package_format                          package_format

As you can see there is an unmatched "orders_id" in the INSERT list just a couple of columns before logged_in.  You need to get the column alignment fixed.
```

Comment: I tryied and returns the same error  `"ERROR: column "logged_in" is of type boolean but expression is of type character varying Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression." `
I also tried `DECODE(oc.logged_in, true, 'true', 'false')::Bool`  and returns this error  `"ERROR: cannot cast type text to boolean" `
I am using it in `SELECT ... DECODE(oc.logged_in, true, 'true', 'false') ... `

Comment: Your 2nd attempt won't work as you cannot cast a string to boolean or boolean to string. You can cast a boolean  to INT (becomes 1 or 0).  The code I posted works and I'll update my answer w/ more details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the correspondence between the fields. It worked after removing the fiels with "order_id". To cast in Redshift there are 2 options:

1. CONVERT ( type, expression )
2. CAST ( expression AS type ) or expression :: type

font: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CAST_function.html#convert-function